Is there a way to display decimal places for values >10 using the tbl_cuminc function in the tidycmprsk package?
I am using the tidycmprsk package along with the tbl_cuminc() function to create a summary table of cumulative incidence. Currently, values below 10 are displayed with one decimal place, while values above 10 are rounded to the nearest whole number.
How can I modify this so that values greater than 10 are also displayed with one decimal place?
For example, in the example below from the tidycmprsk website (https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/tidycmprsk/), I would like to show 24% as 24.X% (16.X%, 33.X%).
Also, I would like to thank the tidycmprsk team for developing such a great package!
library(tidycmprsk)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tidycmprsk':
#>   method                    from     
#>   global_pvalue_fun.tidycrr gtsummary

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) |> 
  tbl_cuminc(times = c(12, 24), label_header = "**Month {time}**") |> 
  gtsummary::as_kable()




Characteristic
Month 12
Month 24




Chemotherapy Treatment




Drug A
3.1% (0.82%, 8.0%)
24% (16%, 33%)


Drug B
8.8% (4.3%, 15%)
32% (23%, 42%)



Created on 2024-09-24 with reprex v2.1.1

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sure, just use the estimate_fun argument to change the default fun that formats the estimates.
library(tidycmprsk)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tidycmprsk':
#>   method                    from     
#>   global_pvalue_fun.tidycrr gtsummary

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) |> 
  tbl_cuminc(
    times = c(12, 24), 
    label_header = "**Month {time}**",
    estimate_fun = gtsummary::label_style_number(scale = 100, digits = 1)
  ) |> 
  gtsummary::as_kable()




Characteristic
Month 12
Month 24




Chemotherapy Treatment




Drug A
3.1% (0.8%, 8.0%)
24.5% (16.5%, 33.4%)


Drug B
8.8% (4.3%, 15.3%)
32.4% (23.5%, 41.5%)



Created on 2024-09-24 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you!
The below slight adjustment worked for me
estimate_fun = function(x) gtsummary::style_number(x, scale = 100, digits = 1)

Yes, you'll need your modification if you haven't updated gtsummary in a few months.
